# MATLAB: how to divide and distribute a list of cell arrays over workers in a parallel loop?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have a question about parallelizing code in MATLAB. I use MATLAB 2017a.

Let's say I have a cell array:

```
A = { A1, ..., A10}
```

and these matrices are quite big ( size > 10000 ). Now I want to start manipulating these matrices in a parallelpool. In fact, ther first worker needs only **`A1`**, the second worker needs only **`A2`** and so on.

I have now this code;

```
parfor i = 1:10
    matrix = A{i};
    blabla = manipulate(Ai);
    save(blabla);
end
```

I think that MATLAB gives every worker all the matrices in `A` but this is not really needed. Is there a way to say:
"Give i-th worker **only** matrix **`Ai`**"?

Comment: Possibly,  

[Distributed Arrays](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/distributed-arrays.html)

are what you are after:

Since you are using cell arrays, you could use the 

[distributed.cell](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/distributed.cell.html)
class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the documentation for variables in `parfor` loops](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html), specifically [sliced variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html), it appears as though the cell array `A` in your example meets the criteria to be treated as a sliced variable by default. You shouldn't have to do anything special. You may want to confirm that all the [listed criteria](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html#bq_ysmm-1) are met, and take a look at each variable to see how they are used both inside and outside your `parfor` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to manually check if my variables are separated?

Comment: @Koen: I don't know offhand of a way to confirm that a sliced variable is in fact a sliced variable. Perhaps you could call [`memory`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html) before and during the `parfor` loop to confirm you aren't getting unexpected memory spikes (i.e. duplication instead of distribution)?

Answer (score 0):

You want [spmd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/spmd.html) blocks. That way, you explicitly handle the slicing of the parallel data, rather than letting Matlab do it automagically with the `parfor` block.

```
parpool('myprofile',10)
spmd
   i = labindex; 
   B = foo(A{i});
end
for i = 1:10
   bar(B{i});
end
```